# is there a virtual Listbox with headers in Delphi XE?

Tags: delphi, header, listbox, virtual, delphi-xe

Sorry, background's a little convoluted on this one... I am in the process of converting a D5 project to DXE...  It has a listbox with several thousand items.  A full progressive text search is done on these items with each keystroke in the searchbox. In D5 (pre-virtual lists), I had to make my own virtual listbox using the LMD listbox (as there were several columns with headers in the listbox), a separate scrollbar and an Array of records.  The Listbox would then be populated as the user navigated through the search results or by modifying the search. This performed very well but since now virtual listboxes are native to Delphi I was going to convert my custom listbox to the native one but I cannot find a listbox component with headers that is virtual-capable.  Help?

Is there a component available that has virtual lists and headers/columns?

I forgot to mention: I am aware of Soft Gems [VirtualTreeView](http://www.soft-gems.net/index.php?option=com_frontpage&Itemid=1) components - these are excellent and is probably what I'll be using but...  Is there a way in DXE to accomplish this without 3rd party utilities? I'm concerned that I'm missing something obvious in DXE as I've only been using it for about a month.

Comment: You can use TListView in virtual mode. The example should be (I hope) available in your Delphi's `\Demos\Virtual Listview` directory.

Comment: Listbox with tab stops + header control will give ya an desired result

Comment: You can also use `TListBox` in virtual mode: set `Style` to `lbVirtual` or `lbVirtualOwnerDraw`.

Comment: @TOndrej OP is well aware of native virtual list boxes in Delphi, but is missing column headers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`TListView` is a thin wrapper around the Windows list view common control. Run it in virtual mode with report view style to achieve what I believe you are asking for.

---

In order to set up a virtual list view you need to set `OwnerData` to `True` and supply an `OnData` event handler.

```
procedure TVirtualListViewForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ListView1.ViewStyle := vsReport;
  ListView1.Columns.Add.Caption := 'Column1';
  ListView1.Columns.Add.Caption := 'Column2';
  ListView1.OwnerData := True;
  ListView1.OnData := ListViewData;
  ListView1.Items.Count := 42;
end;

procedure TVirtualListViewForm.ListViewData(Sender: TObject; Item: TListItem);
begin
  Item.Caption := Format('Column 0, index %d', [Item.Index]);
  Item.SubItems.Add(Format('Column 1, index %d', [Item.Index]));
end;
```

For your needs an `OnDataFind` may be needed to implement the progressive text search.

Comment: I can see how to edit a view style for the TListView but not how to run it in virtual mode. What am I missing?

Comment: To further clarify... "VirtualMode" is not displayed as a design-time property for TListView in my Delphi XE. Even if I try it programmatically: `ListView1.VirtualMode := true` it states that VirtualMode is an invalid property. I must be missing something obvious but for the life of me I cannot find it.  Help!?!?

Comment: Sorry I missed your comment. You need to implement the OnData event handler and possibly a couple of its relatives. You should be able to work it out from the docs I think.

Comment: @b-p I've edited the answer to give you some hints for making progress. I hope it helps.

Comment: you're awesome!  I'll try it later when I get back from my "other job"

Answer (score 0):

You can use my component TDzListHeader, available at GitHub: https://github.com/digao-dalpiaz/DzListHeader

This component allows you to create columns in a TCollection and you should drop a TListBox inside the TListHeader, and link them.

[DzListHeader example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KdN9j.png)

All usage and detailed documentation are available at github project.